# Problem with unmarshalling in LogicSOAPHandler inJax-WS

Tags: web-services

I have a SEI as

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding
(   
    style = javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT,
    use = javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL
)
@HandlerChain(file = "securityhandler.xml")
public interface UserService
{
    @WebMethod
    public AuthenticateResponse authenticateUser(AuthenticateRequest request,@WebParam(header = true, mode = Mode.IN) ApplicationCredentials credential);
}
```

I am using wsgen to generate server side class files and wsdl. What I noticed that wsgen generates wrapper on my request(AuthenticateRequest) as

```
package com.ecourt.ws.jaxws;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import com.ecourt.ws.impl.request.AuthenticateRequest;

@XmlRootElement(name = "authenticateUser", namespace = "http://ws.ecourt.com/")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "authenticateUser", namespace = "http://ws.ecourt.com/")
public class AuthenticateUser {

    @XmlElement(name = "arg0", namespace = "")
    private AuthenticateRequest arg0;

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     returns AuthenticateRequest
     */
    public AuthenticateRequest getArg0() {
        return this.arg0;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param arg0
     *     the value for the arg0 property
     */
    public void setArg0(AuthenticateRequest arg0) {
        this.arg0 = arg0;
    }

}
```

Now I am using a LogicalHandler to intercept SOAP Message and tried to unmarshall the payload to AuthenticateRequest, it throws exception:

javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://ws.ecourt.com/", local:"authenticateUser"). Expected elements are <{}authenticateRequest>,<{}baseRequest>

the handle message implementation of my handler is

```
@Override
    public boolean handleMessage(LogicalMessageContext messageContext) {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("in handle messgae of AuthenticationHandler");
            Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean)
            messageContext.get (MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
            if(outboundProperty == false)
            {
                JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(com.ecourt.ws.impl.request.AuthenticateRequest.class);
                Object obj = messageContext.getMessage().getPayload(jc);
}
}
catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This is the part of the xsd

```
<xs:element name="authenticateUser" type="tns:authenticateUser"/>


  <xs:complexType name="authenticateUser">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="arg0" type="tns:authenticateRequest" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

I just want to UnMarshall payLoad directly to AuthenticateRequest not AuthenticateUser generated by WSGen. Is there any way to do it? Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This is solved, I needed to use the other overloaded method in LogicalMessage Class that is:
Source source = messageContext.getMessage().getPayload();
And with the source we can handle the complete Soap Address.

Thanks